# Possible conflicts beteeen Xfce/Thunar and Cinnamon/Nemo

Tags: xfce, cinnamon, thunar, nemo

On Ubuntu and Linux Mint websites and forums people usually say that these two desktops can be used as parallel sessions, in Ubuntu or Mint without any problem.

I have used a lot Xfce and Xubuntu and have found that Thunar and Nautilus (and nautilus forks like Nemo) are fighting to control the desktop or be the default file manager for Firefox. So, I stay away from Nautilus when using Xfce.

But now I have installed LM 17 Qiana Xfce, and then the cinnamon desktop. I like both and I would like to give it a try.

Only that in the Cinnamon session the desktop is not usable at all. I suppose that now it's Thunar that has taken over and disabled Nemo for the desktop, while the Cinnamon session sees no desktop file manager at all.

What should I do to impose Nemo as main file manager in Cinnamon and use the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use LM 17 Qiana, cinnamon desktop and nemo was deault file manager which was my original install. I switched to Thunar and uninstalled nemo I assume you can simply uninstall thunar and you will have your desktop back to cinnamon.

It is Thunar making the desktop unable to add launchers to it.